# Laptop as wifi repeater is slowing down internet speed

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, bandwidth

My laptop has 2 wireless cards, onboard wifi, and USB wifi (3 dbi high gain).
I have set up USB wifi to connect to access point, and onboard wifi as a hotspot (nmcli AP mode, named HostedAP).

Speedtest on laptop shows ~40Mbps connection speed, but I connect a device to HostedAP it's only showing ~7Mbps.

I checked both APs in WifiAnalyzer android app, it is showing that actual AP is using channel 3 + 7 (2452 - 2413 = 40 MHz channel width), but HostedAP is using only channel 1 (2423 -2401 = 22MHz channel width).

Thinking 22MHz channel width is bottle neck, I did bandwidth testing between a device and HostedAP using iperf, It's showing bandwidth of ~37Mbps.

```
[  4] local 10.42.0.252 port 56542 connected to 10.42.0.1 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.01   sec  4.25 MBytes  35.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.01-2.01   sec  4.25 MBytes  35.7 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.01-3.01   sec  3.88 MBytes  32.5 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.01-4.00   sec  4.88 MBytes  41.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.01   sec  4.12 MBytes  34.3 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.01-6.00   sec  4.75 MBytes  40.2 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.01   sec  4.75 MBytes  39.6 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.01-8.01   sec  4.25 MBytes  35.7 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.01-9.01   sec  4.50 MBytes  37.5 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.01-10.00  sec  4.50 MBytes  38.3 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  44.1 MBytes  37.0 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  44.1 MBytes  37.0 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Please guide me and share pointers on what could be the problem in this setup and how to diagnose it.

Comment: Can you switch to a non-overlapping frequency and re-test?

Comment: @user1686 I did various experiments including switching AP to channel 13. This increased internet speed from 7 Mbps to 10 Mbps. But still, it is nowhere near the 40Mbps I receive on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The USB interface doesn't have the bandwidth to work as hard as it needs to for repeating. A spare minipci slot is needed but not seen many laptops with those now. Recommend purchasing a GL-mt300n-v2 https://www.gl-inet.com/products/gl-mt300n-v2/ as a less power hungry, more efficient alternative.